# CiviMail sending delayed - how do I configure a cron job?

Tags: civimail, cron-job

I am trying to set up CiviMail however I cannot seem to get my emails to go. They remain scheduled.However, when I execute them manually at administer->system settings-> scheduled jobs they go. When I click the edit button , no matter what selection I make on run frequency, that is hourly, daily or every time cron job is run, the emails are never sent.(Until I choose execute now option). I have tried reading on [setting up a cron job](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviMail+Installation) and [managing Scheduled Jobs](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs) but can not really understand. I am running CiviCRM 4.6.3 and Drupal 7. I have admin privileges and can access command line if need be.

Answer (score 1):

I sounds like you either don't have a cron job configured to run the Scheduled Jobs at regular intervals, or you don't have it configured correctly.

What have you tried using as the cron command when you tried to set that up, and/or what errors does it give? (Edit your question above with further information)

Comment: Does your cron command function when you use it from the command line?

Comment: I was able to get it to work by using wget -O - -q -t 1 \
http://mysite.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=cronjob&pass=cronjobpass&key=sitekey. I ran the URL on my browser and the mail were sent although I am not sure how to use it to set cron job to run regularly

Comment: If you have a command line command that is working I think you can simply set it up in a cron job. Options on how you would set the cron job depends on your server/hosting situation -- you can add cron jobs from the command line or through a GUI such as cPanel, and just tell the server to periodically run the `wget` command that you tested above.

Comment: Ok will do that